# Error: The client '#' with object id '#' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/write'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops, cicd

Using a service principal I am trying to update the secret value of keyvault. The service principal does have all the permissions to update the secret value. This code is working
in the local machine in Powershell ISE, but not in the pipeline.

This is the code I am using

```
$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString $MyPat -AsPlainText -Force
$SecuredApplicationSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString "$AzureApplicationSecret" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AzureApplicationId , $SecuredApplicationSecret)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $AzureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
$secret = Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName -Name $secretName -SecretValue $secretvalue -Expires $validToDate
```

The error that I am getting is:

> Error: The client '#' with object id '#' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/write' over scope '/subscriptions/#/resourceGroups/#providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/#' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Kindly help me resolve this issue so that the code also works in the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Azure Powershell task in Azure DevOps and don't forget to add the agent to use the oAuth token. It should work as well.
[Azure Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines)
Choose Azure Powershell Script Task
[image]
Enable **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your Key Vault -> Access control (IAM) -> Role assignments. Search for the service principal you are using with its name. Please check the role of your service principal. You can assign it with "Key Vault Administrator" role for test. Then run the pipeline again to see if it works.

[image]

In addition to using "Update-AzKeyVaultSecret", you can also use Azure CLI to update the secret. You will use [az login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli-service-principal) to sign in with a service principal and use [az keyvault secret set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-set) to update your secret.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <secret> --tenant <tenant>
      az keyvault secret set --name MySecretName --vault-name MyKeyVault --value MyValue
```

Comment: Hi @user10434309, have you checked the suggestion above? If it works, it's suggested that you could accept the answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), so that others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly. If you have any question or need any help, feel free to let me know. Thanks.